# ReentrantLock tryLock()

Tags: java, thread-synchronization, reentrantlock

This is the source code of ReentrantLock#tryLock:

```
public boolean tryLock() {
        return sync.nonfairTryAcquire(1);
}
```

My question is that:
 There are two types of Synchronizers: FairSync and NonFairSync in the ReentrantLock. Why only the NonFairSync is used?

Answer (score 0):

**Non-fair** means that when the lock is ready to be obtained by a new thread, the lock gives no guarantees to the fairness of who obtains the lock (assuming there are multiple threads requesting the lock at the time). In other words, it is conceivable that one thread might be continuously starved because other threads always manage to arbitrarily get the lock instead of it.

**Fair** mode acts more like first-come-first-served, where threads are guaranteed some level of fairness that they will obtain the lock in a fair manner (e.g. before a thread that started waiting long after).

If Reentrant Locks were to be fair, then by above definition of **Fair**, lock wouldn't be given to the same thread, but the other thread which has been waiting.